# python function next line is not executed

Tags: python

I have written a simple code for find whether the number is even or odd.

Here is my code:

```
print("To find number is even or odd")
print("Enter the number ")
def is_even():
  num=int(input())    
if(num % 2 == 0):
  print("Even")
else:
  print("Odd")
```

When I run my code it shows me the error :

To find number is even or odd
Enter the number

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/even.py", line 6, in <module>
    if(num % 2 == 0):
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Can someone explain why next line after function is not get executed even if I replace the input to any print statement it will not get executed.

Comment: Please fix the question indentation to match how your file is indented. If the question indentation is correct, then that's your problem. The `if` is outside the function definition since python is whitespace delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is messed up (remember that python has fun indentation rules).  In addition, you can't have an underscore in a function identifier.  Right now, the scope of `num` is only in the function `iseven()`, so anything outside can't read it.  Here is the corrected code.

```
print("To find number is even or odd")
print("Enter the number ")
def iseven():
    num=int(input())    
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        print("Even")
    else:
        print("Odd")
iseven()
```

Comment: `is_even` is never called.

Comment: And that is also an issue.  I was specifically fixing his code.

Comment: Underscores _are_ allowed in function names. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: are you sure, I have had trouble using it as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` variable is only defined inside the `is_even()` function, and so its local to that function, not accessible outside, and also you are never calling that function. To me it looks like you intended to define the checking part of the code as well inside the function, if so, you need to indent the part after that correctly inside the function, indentation is important in python, it is used to define blocks. If so, you need to call the function after defining it, otherwise it would not work -

```
print("To find number is even or odd")
print("Enter the number ")
def is_even():
  num=int(input())    
  if(num % 2 == 0):
    print("Even")
  else:
    print("Odd")

is_even()
```